# Is there any way to decrypt a hardware-encrypted internal SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, encryption, apfs, data-recovery

My mid-2019 MacBook Pro has a fault on the mainboard that causes it to crash soon after (sometimes while) it boots. I’m trying to get the data off the internal SSD. When I boot it in target mode (by pressing ‘T’ during startup), I can access the SSD as an external FireWire drive on another Mac. It doesn’t immediately crash then, but when I start copying files, it eventually does. However, to my surprise, I was able to make a complete bytewise copy of the SSD using `dd`, which took 3 days and didn't cause it to crash. The copy seems to be intact; I can mount the unencrypted volumes on it from the image.

Unfortunately, it turns out that the internal SSD is [hardware-encrypted](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208862), and the encrypted volume on it can’t be mounted from the image. Trying to unwrap the container’s keybag as if it were software-encrypted results in garbage data with an incorrect checksum. Neither `diskutil` nor any of the open-source APFS tools that I found are able to unlock the volume.

My question is whether there’s any way to get around this, for instance by emulating the hardware encryption in software or by `dd`ing from a different device file that mirrors a decrypted version of the disk. I’d rather not have to copy the data piecewise in between crashes :-).

Comment: One option is to completely wipe and reinstall (As just `APFS` and not `APFS-Encrypted`, but I will research on this to get an alternate solution :).

Comment: I think you are referring to FileVault. Does this documentation help? : https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchlp2560/mac

Comment: @Rishon_JR: I don't think I am. As far as I understand, FileVault and hardware encryption are two separate things. I didn't activate FileVault on this machine, as far as I remember.